# Missing argument 2 for the function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a function in wordpress function.php, but I am getting an error:

> Missing argument 2 for get_appcara_child() in C:\wamp\www\appcara\wp-content\themes\appkara\functions.php on line 617

The function is giving the correct output, but I don't know why it is displaying this warning

My function.php is

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_appcara_child',2 );
function get_appcara_child($post,$parent)
{
    echo $post;

    echo $parent;
}
```

Calling at page.php

```
$child= get_appcara_child($post->ID , $post->post_parent);
```

Comment: is `$post->post_parent` always set?

Comment: By using `add_action()` does Wordpress not call the function at some point (probably at initialization)? If so, are you sure Wordpress gives it two arguments? If not then you should look into that. Have you read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) thoroughly?

Comment: issue resolved . i have removed the add_action( 'init', 'get_appcara_child',2 );

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The format is:

```
add_action( HOOK, CALLBACK, PRIORITY, NUMBER OF PARAMETERS );
```

You set the priority to `2` and it should be the parameters (`$post,$parent`). Correction:

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_appcara_child', 10, 2 );
```

*PS: `10` is the default priority.*

Answer (score -2):

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
    (function(w, d) { 
        var s = d.createElement('script'); 
        s.src = '//cdn.adpushup.com/39884/adpushup.js'; 
        s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; 
        (d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(s); 
    })(window, document);</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your solution.